# Unwanted R code echo when compiling PDF with knitr

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, sweave

I have an .Rnw file that contains the code below. Run `knitr::knit()` once and the R code doesn't doesn't echo. Run `knitr::knit()` a second time and the R code echoes in the PDF. Why? How can I prevent R code from echoing?

```
<<load_chapter_2, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE,cache=TRUE>>=

options(digits=2)

opts_chunk$set(eval=TRUE, results = "hide", echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.height=5, fig.width=5, fig.pos="!ht", fig.align='center')

@


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Required to insert dummy text

% \usepackage{nameref} commented out as was causing extra \else error

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{placeins} % to control figure placement with \FloatBarrier

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{array} % for line breaks in table

\usepackage[comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}


\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Header}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

<<plot_1>>=

plot(1)

@
\FloatBarrier


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't cache your setup block - this means that your `options` and `opts_chunk$set` won't be run on subsequent calls of `knit()`. `cache = TRUE` should be used for blocks of code that produce results where if the code hasn't changed, the results won't have changed either. However, you also need to be careful of dependencies.

See http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/ for more detail. Look in particular at the section labelled 'Important notes' which has the following:

> It is extremely important to note that usually a chunk that has
>   side-effects should not be cached. Although knitr tries to retain the
>   side-effects from print(), there are still other side-effects that are
>   not preserved. Here are some cases that you must not use cache for a
>   chunk:
>
> 1. setting R options like `options('width')` or `pdf.options()` or any other options in knitr like `opts_chunk$set()`, `opts_knit$set()` and
>      `knit_hooks$set()`
> 2. loading packages via `library()` in a cached chunk and these packages will be used by uncached chunks (it is entirely OK to load
>      packages in a cached chunk and use them only in cached chunks because
>      knitr saves the list of packages for cached chunks, but uncached
>      chunks are unable to know which packages are loaded in previous cached
>      chunks)
>
> Otherwise next time the chunk will be skipped and all the settings in
>   it will be ignored. You have to use `cache=FALSE` explicitly for these
>   chunks.

Comment: Just to check can `cache = TRUE` be used inside `opts_chunk$set()`?

Comment: @luciano yes, but then any other chunks that set options etc. will need an explicit `cache = FALSE`

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `cache = F`. I think the reason is that with `cache = TRUE` the second time the code is stored in memory and the `echo = F` is ignored.